# Gradle module dependency not found

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, aws-sdk

I just installed Android Studio 3.1.4 on Windows 10, and upon creating an empty test project, and building it, I'm getting the error:

```
Cannot find JAR 'aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.6.jar' required by module 'gradle-resources-s3' using classpath or distribution directory
```

It is referencing gradle 4.4 in my documents\.gradle folder. Anyone has any idea how to go about this problem?

Comment: Dont know why this could happen but u can try adding dependency for a workaround  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kms/1.11.6

Comment: Where should it be added please? It looks like this is not a project specific issue

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a blockage for an internet security suite. The suite scans all incoming jar dependencies while they are extracted from the global gradle zip file. For some reason, a select few packages are flagged, and thus gradle syncing fails.